# C# Passing Arguments Through Context Menu

Tags: c#, menu, arguments

so I made a program that creates a registry key on the pc, that adds an option to push your file to your device. (The program itself pushes files to your Android sd card.)

Everything works well, or at least should, once I figure out this issue.  When I right-click on an item and choose my command (which is to open up with my program) my program just opens up, but no arguments are passed.

A month ago, I designed a program that opens when the user double clicks (just double click, not right-clicking through context menu) a file, it opened the specific program, and from there I was able to grab the arguments.

Why can't I from the context menu?

Thanks, sorry for lengthy post.

And here's part of my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string c = textBox3.Text;

          string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

          try
          {

              string location = args[1];
              MessageBox.Show(location);
              //For testing purposes only

              Properties.Settings.Default.thinglocation = location;
              Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
              Process();
          }

          catch
          {

          }
```

Here's the registry code. BTw string c is "C:\File push.exe" the location of my program.

```
 string MenuName = "*\\shell\\NewMenuOption";
                string Command = "*\\shell\\NewMenuOption\\command";

                RegistryKey regmenu = null;
                RegistryKey regcmd = null;
                try
                {
                    regmenu = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(MenuName);
                    if (regmenu != null)
                        regmenu.SetValue("", "Push to Android");
                    regcmd = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(Command);
                    if (regcmd != null)
                        regcmd.SetValue("", c +"%1");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (regmenu != null)
                        regmenu.Close();
                    if (regcmd != null)
                        regcmd.Close();
```

Comment: you need to show us the registry key you have created, and probably you need to add %1 to that registry key

Comment: Did you check the values in "EventArgs e" OR in "string[] args"? I would suggest check that to see if item's properties (like filename) is part of the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have created a registry entry which creates the context menu item which you are using to launch your program.  Likelihood is that you need to add ' %1' after the name of the exe you want to launch.  In the context menu registry entries %1 represents the selected file, so adding this should launch your program and provide the name of the selected file as the single argument.

the reason why it worked before with the double click is that windows will launch the default program for the file double clicked, with the double clicked file as the argument.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion I tried it, but I now I received the open with program list.  I think I'm typing something in wrong with the registry.

Comment: Nevermind, just tried it again with a few adjustments and worked perfectly!!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: I assume that your issue was the fact that you had no space before your %1 in the example code above?  If not the can you post the final fixed code showing what your 'few adjustments' were to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking in the sender or the EventArgs parameters?  I would think their might be something in there.  That's just a guess though.  If its just a double click then why would there be any arguments?  Maybe I am just misunderstanding that point.  Anyways, maybe that helps.  If not maybe you could clarify a little bit where the arguments are supposed to come from.

Erik

Comment: Erik, I think you got a downvote because you didn't really answer the question but don't be disheartened, it happens.  I think with a double click windows will launch the default program and provide the name of the doubleclicked fiole as the argument to the executable

Comment: Thanks Sam...There must be a good reason for that.  I would think that the file being run (and double clicked) would be the executable in most cases.  Otherwise it would be a shortcut which itself would have the correct arguments.  Anyways, seems like the guy got his answer.  I need to try to give back because I have gotten enough help from people like you.  Thanks again.

Comment: think of if you double click a .xls file, it will open with Excel by default.  Windows just calls excel.exe passing the file name and path as the command line arguments.